# Detaching functions in javascript while retaining their context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is it possible to detach functions in javascript while allowing them to retain access to their context?

For example suppose we have a `ViewportScroller` instance called vc.  We can get the current scroll position by calling:

```
vc.getScrollPosition()
```

Is it possible to detach it like this:

```
cont scrollPosition = vc.getScrollPosition
```

While ensuring that it will still work and be able to access everything it needs to work or do we always need to wrap `vc` like this:

```
const scrollPostion = ()=>vc.getScrollPosition()
```

Comment: `let scrollPostion = vc.getScrollPosition.bind(vc)`. See [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [*What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `.bind`

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
cont scrollPosition = vc.getScrollPosition.bind(vc)
```