# why when click on an item, all item opens

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, accordion

I have list with an accordion, when you click on a item, all items opens, I need to open just one,
I understand that a loop is needed to iterate over all the items and apply the class to a specific one, but how to do this, please help
component:

```
  <ul class="accordion accordion__trigger"
      :class="{'accordion__trigger_active': visible}"
      @click="open">
    <li class="accordion__item" v-for="category in MAIN_CATS">
        <nuxt-link exact no-prefetch active-class="link-active"
                   :to="`/category/${category.id}`"
                   class="menu-button">
          {{ category.title }}
        </nuxt-link>
        <div class="accordion__content">
          <div class="menu-sub-list" v-show="visible">
              <ul class="sub-list">
                <li class="menu-item"
                    v-for="sub in SUB_CATS(category.id)"
                    :key="sub.id">
                  <nuxt-link :to="`/category/${sub.id}`" class="menu-button">
                    {{ sub.title }}
                  </nuxt-link>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

code:

```
name: "acc",
  data() {
    return {
      index: null,
      Accordion: {
        count: 0,
        active: null
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'MAIN_CATS',
      'SUB_CATS'
    ]),
    visible() {
      return this.index === this.Accordion.active;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'GET_CATEGORIES_LIST',
    ]),
    open() {
      if (this.visible) {
        this.Accordion.active = null;
      } else {
        this.Accordion.active = this.index;
      }
    },
    start(el) {
      el.style.height = el.scrollHeight + "px";
    },
    end(el) {
      el.style.height = "";
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.index = this.Accordion.count++;
  },
  mounted() {
    this.GET_CATEGORIES_LIST()
  },
```

I have list with an accordion, when you click on a item, all items opens, I need to open just one,
I understand that a loop is needed to iterate over all the items and apply the class to a specific one, but how to do this, please help

Comment: Right now your click handler is on the whole `ul` element, so whatever in that you click it will trigger the method. Then, you simply set `this.index` as the active value. Looks like `index` is always null? Or how do you set it? Also, since visisble is a computed, it can only be true or false. But you need to have that value different for each item in the loop. Use a method instead that gets the current index and use that method in the loop, or better make a computed list and add a visible value to each entry.

Comment: did it like here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753165/toggle-only-accordion-clicked-vue-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple differences between your code and code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753165/toggle-only-accordion-clicked-vue-js) that you referred to.

You can notice that `@click` is placed in the same line as `v-for`.

The main reason for that is to be able to easily access `index` of each element in a loop.

---

Not to overcomplicate it for you, I created a basic [use case scenario](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-water-wmc9w?file=/src/App.vue:0-1360):

```
<template>
  <div id="accordion" class="accordion-container">
    <ul
      v-for="(category, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      class="accordion accordion__trigger"
      :class="{'accordion__trigger_active': visible===index}"
      @click="visible=index"
    >
      <li class="accordion__item">
        {{ category.title }}
        <div class="accordion__content">
          <div class="menu-sub-list" v-show="visible===index">
            <ul class="sub-list">
              <li class="menu-item">{{ category.sub }}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "trial-page",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: "Accordion 1",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
          sub: "Pellentesque risus mi"
        },
        {
          title: "Accordion 2",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
          sub: "Pellentesque risus mi"
        },
        {
          title: "Accordion 3",
          text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
          sub: "Pellentesque risus mi"
        }
      ],
      visible: null
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.accordion__trigger_active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

---

You can see that the idea is to operate with `index` value that is assigned to `visible` data property in this case.

We simply check if the `visible` is equal to the currently pressed item with the value of `index`.

With that we conditionally `v-show` element and trigger the class `:class="{'accordion__trigger_active': visible===index}"`.

---

Note that if you had more `v-for` loops in the same component then you would need to make sure the value used for `visible` is always unique, for that you could simply add some string to it like:

`@click="visible=index+'category'"`

---

Also remember to assign a `:key` when using `v-for`.

Example:
`v-for="(category, index) in items" :key="index"`