# How could i use Bind in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bind

Helloo, I’m trying to understand how “bind” is working. Could you explaine me how could I use “bind” to getthe same result on both console.log(this)?

```
document.querySelector("h").addEventListener("click", test1);
test(1);
function test1(){
    console.log(this);
    function test2(){
        console.log(this);
    }
    test2();
}
```

Comment: Probably by test2().bind(this);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: Nimeshka Srimal no, it dosen't work!