# that.setState is not a function.(expo react native)

Tags: react-native, expo

This is my function in class:

```
loadFeed = () => {
    this.setState=({
        refresh: true,
        collection: []
    });

    var that = this;

    database.ref('collection').orderByChild('date').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
        if(exists) data = snapshot.val();
        var temp = that.state.employees;

        for(var item in data){
            var Obj = data[photo];

            database.ref('users').child(Obj.name).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
                const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
                if(exists) data = snapshot.val();

                temp.push({
                    id: key,
                    name: Obj.name
                });

                that.setState({
                    refresh: false,
                    loading: false
                });

            }).catch(error => console.log(error)); 
        }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

In above code I am getting this error:

> that.setState is not a function.
>
> ```
>   (In 'that.setState({
>             refresh: false,
>             loading: false
>           })', 'that.setState' is an instance of Object)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState=({
    refresh: true,
    collection: []
});
```

should be

```
this.setState({
    refresh: true,
    collection: []
});
```

Comment: Yep, you got it! I thought the problem was related to binding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var that = this;` you should bind this into the context in which you are trying to use `this`.

From https://developer.mozilla.org :

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```
const module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}

const unboundGetX = module.getX;
console.log(unboundGetX()); // The function gets invoked at the global scope
// expected output: undefined

const boundGetX = unboundGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX());
// expected output: 42
```

If you are unfamiliar with that, you should look into what binding is in JavaScript:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind
- https://javascript.info/bind
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/
- [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)