# Constantly getting "x is not a function" error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, bind, es6-class

I'm trying to call a method inside another method but I get error "x is not a function".
The methods are in very same class.
I'm new in node so I don't get its errors at all. My code is :

file app.js :

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pkg = require("./app/b.js");

const port = 3001;

pkg("Hi");

app.listen(port, () => console.log("app is running on port " + port));
```

and my b.js file is like:

```js
class BFile{
  y(str){
    // some irrelative codes
    x(str)
  }

  x(arg){
    // some code
  }
}

const obj = new BFile()
module.exports = obj.y
```

note: I tried to use "this" before calling x method ( like: this.x(str); ) but "this" is undefined

Comment: -> `this.x(str)`, and you may even bind it with `module.exports = obj.y.bind(obj)`

Comment: yes but as I mentioned, "this" is detected as undefined. let me try binding

Comment: Use `module.exports = obj.y.bind(obj)` and then `this.x(..)` will work.

Comment: bind method works :) thank you both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to call a method of the current object and not a global method
You should call it using `this` so it will be called from the current object
You also will need to bind the method to the created object in the constructor   Either manually or you can use [auto-bind](https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind)

```js
class BFile{
  constructor () {
    this.x = this.x.bind(this);
    // Or autobind(this);
  }

  y(str) {
    ...
    this.x(str);
    ...
  }

  x(arg) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The much cleaner way to bind would be to do it in the constructor.

```js
class BFile {
  constructor() {
    this.y = this.y.bind(this);
    this.x = this.x.bind(this);
  }

  y(str) {
    this.x(str); // this is needed here.
  }

  x(arg) {
    // some code
  }
}

const obj = new BFile();
module.exports = obj.y;
```

Then you should be able to use `this` just fine.

You can learn more about usage of `bind()` in JavaScript [here (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method), or [here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).