# When using bind() on a Javascript number, what does the console.log() output represent?

Tags: javascript

I came across a tutorial on `bind()` and the output is `[Number: 1]`. Why is the number represented like this when logged as the context of the bind function?

```js
const func = function() {
  console.log(this)
}.bind(1);

func();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: your output is `{}` not `1`

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial in question?

Answer (score 1):

Bind sets the "this" property to whatever the argument is that it is passed. In this case, since 1 is a primitive it is wrapped in the Number object (this is how JS handles primitives being used as objects) so the this context is the Number object containing 1.

Comment: Thanks. How should I interpret the output syntax though? It's not an array but it has square brackets? On the other hand, the colon leads me to think, as your answer suggests, an object.

Comment: @jjkl I'm not as sure about this one, but the behavior is the same whether the bind argument is 1 or new Number(1). I imagine it relates to how this is treated internally by the constructor/boxing process.

Comment: @jjkl it is just the way Nodejs represents the Object [Number: 1], but chrome/firefox represents it as Number {1} in the dev console

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of [`bind`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind) is the target to bind to the function.

In this case a number literal is supplied.

Internally, `bind` boxes the number literal into a `Number` object, equivalent to `Number(1)`.

This object is then printed to the console.

Where, internally, `bind` performs the boxing, I am unsure.

In the spec the operation [BoundFunctionCreate](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-boundfunctioncreate) assigns the new target to the `[[BoundThis]]` internal slot.

> 9.4.1.3 **BoundFunctionCreate** ( targetFunction, boundThis, boundArgs )
>
> The abstract operation BoundFunctionCreate with arguments targetFunction, boundThis and boundArgs is used to specify the creation of new Bound Function exotic objects. It performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Assert: Type(targetFunction) is Object.
> 2. Let proto be ? targetFunction.[GetPrototypeOf].
> 3. Let obj be a newly created object.
> 4. Set obj's essential internal methods to the default ordinary object definitions specified in 9.1.
> 5. Set obj.[[Call]] as described in 9.4.1.1.
> 6. If IsConstructor(targetFunction) is true, then
> 7. Set obj.[[Construct]] as described in 9.4.1.2.
> 8. Set obj.[[Prototype]] to proto.
> 9. Set obj.[[Extensible]] to true.
> 10. Set obj.[[BoundTargetFunction]] to targetFunction.
> 11. Set obj.[[BoundThis]] to boundThis.
> 12. Set obj.[[BoundArguments]] to boundArgs.
> 13. Return obj.