# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation') with fetch

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, navigation, fetch

I try my best to make a Sign-in form with React native but :

- I can't make a redirection to 'App', the error message is : (TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')])

  ```
  try {
    fetch('http://93.xxx.xx.xx:5151/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: formBody,
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
        } else {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch [error : " + response.status + "]");
          Alert.alert("Error [" + response.status + "] - " + response.statusText);
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          Alert.alert(response.userToken);
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          Alert.alert("Error [" + response.status + "] - " + response.statusText);
        }
      })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  ```

Is anyone know how to do that ?

- I only have one solution so far :

  ```
  fetch('http://93.xxx.xx.xx:5151/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      },
      body: formBody
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
      } else {
        if (res.status == 400) {
          Alert.alert("Error 400 : login rejected because -> " + res.message)
        } else {
          throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${res.status}`);
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(console.error)
  }
  ```

But with this solution i don't know how to save the User token ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a scoping issue , change this :

```
.then(function(response) { // due to this you are losing `this` scope inside it

// due to that, this is not accessible, in result you will get error
this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
```

To :

```
.then((response) => { // <--- Fat arrow is what you need
```

Comment: thanks to you my redirection work well now, 
but  inside the seconde .then my "if (response.ok)" didn't work anymore ...  i have this error : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.ok')

Comment: @Xodarap, that is because you are not returning anything from first .then , `return response` in first `.then` then you will get the value inside second one

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a scope issue. If you want to use "this" in an anonymous function, you need to bind it to your object.
There are two ways to do that:

1) If you use the old function style, the former object don't get automatically bound to it. Therefore you need to bind the parent object manually.
If you want a little more explanation about it, look here: [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

```js
Promise.then(function(res) {
    return "Your return"
}.bind(this));
```

2) The second way is to use the ES6 "Fat arrow"-Function. This works internally a bit different and binds the content of the parent Obejct directly.

```js
Promise.then(res => "Your return");
```

On your second Problem I don't fully understand what your goal is. Do you want the user token in your next route? If so, you should use "setParams":

```js
fetch('http://93.xxx.xx.xx:5151/login', { 
 method: 'POST', 
 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}, 
 body: formBody 
})
.then(res => {
 if(res.ok) {
  this.props.setParams({
    token: res.userToken
  })
  this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
 } else {
  if (res.status == 400) {
    Alert.alert("Error 400 : login rejected because -> " + res.message)
  } else {
    throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${res.status}`);
  }
}})
.catch(console.error)
}}
```