# What is the bind() and why it is being used here

Tags: javascript

```
    this.name = name
}
person.prototype.friends = function(arr){
    var friends = arr.map(function(el){
        return this.name + ' is friend of ' + el
    }.bind(this))
   return friends
  }
let ahmed = new person('Ahmed')
console.log(ahmed.friends(['Mona', 'Khaled']))
```

I didn't understand why we use bind and when we remove it, the this keyword shows the global object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Answer (score 2):

The `bind()` method creates a new function that has the `this` keyword set to the provided value when called.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Example:

```js
const x = function() {
  alert(this) // Alerts window
}

const y = function() {
  alert(this)
}.bind('Something else') // Alerts 'Something else'

x()
y()
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/o4bLk53a/)

Note that this can only be used on function expressions, and not function declarations. For more information, refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801906/12984567

Answer (score 2):

As per definition `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

if you remove `bind()`method then `this` keyword shows the global object because the way javascript `this` keyword works. To understand the working of `this` keyword you can refer [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complete-guide-to-this-in-javascript/).

To understand the working of `bind()` method here are the code snippet.

```js
var obj = {
 key: 'xyz',
 display: function(){
   console.log(this.key);
  }
};

obj.display(); // expected output: xyz

const unboundDisplay = obj.display; 
unboundDisplay(); // The function gets invoked at the global scope
// expected output: undefined

const boundDisplay = unboundDisplay.bind(obj);
boundDisplay(); // expected output: xyz
```

To summarize `bind()` method is used when we assign this function reference to some other variable

Answer (score 1):

```
person.prototype.friends = function(arr){
    var friends = arr.map(function(el){
        return this.name + ' is friend of ' + el
    }.bind(this))
   return friends
  }
```

`bind` makes `this` available inside function. If you don't have bind in the above code, `this` will point `window`, not person. So, without bind, this.name will be undefined.

Comment: Without `bind`, `this` would point to `window`, not `function(...){...}`. Otherwise you are right