# This scoping in java script

Tags: javascript, class, this

I know `this` keyword is evaluated on the basis of how a function is called. I have the following code:

```
name='sohan';
income=23232;
class Person{
    constructor(name,income)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.income=income;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.income);
    }
    getFunc(){
        return this.print;
    }
}

let p1=new Person('bhavuk',10000);
let print=p1.getFunc();
print();
```

My doubt is `print()` should bind this to the global context. I expect 'sohan 23232', but it gives error `name undefined`. Please explain how is this working out. Thanks.

Comment: classes run in strict mode, so the `this` when not specified will be undefined (it won't default to the global object (in browsers the window) like in it does in an object literal).

Comment: @Reyno if we want to answer, I would rather suggest `return this.print.bind(this);` in `getFunc()`.

Comment: No, output in your link is what i expected. My code is working different to what your link suggest.

Comment: @tevemadar yes i was about to change my comment but you just beat me to it!

Comment: To express was Nick said in slightly different words: In strict mode, `this` inside a "normal" function call is `undefined`.

Comment: I find *this* (hehe) outcome a bit misleading: I suggested  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method as something what OP could check, and that link is completely gone now (apart from remaining "Linked" on the right, which no beginner will ever notice).

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the variables `name` and `income` globally without the `let`, `const` or `var` they implicitly become properties of the global object in non strict mode.

Now in the `class Person`, the method `print` is defined. The class being run in strict mode implicitly, the `this` will be `undefined` always when you get the method reference from class instance:

`let print = p1.getFunc();`

In the above snippet the method reference is held in the `print` variable, but the `this` in the `print` function is undefined due to strict mode. So when you run the `print` it will throw an error.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> When a static or prototype method is called without a value for this,
> such as by assigning a variable to the method and then calling it, the
> this value will be undefined inside the method. This behavior will be
> the same even if the "use strict" directive isn't present, because
> code within the class body's syntactic boundary is always executed in
> strict mode.

In order to point `this` to the expected object you can use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the expected `this` to the method reference:

```js
name='sohan';
income=23232;

class Person{
    constructor(name,income)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.income=income;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this.income);
    }
    getFunc(){
        return this.print;
    }
}

let p1=new Person('bhavuk',10000);
let myPrint = p1.getFunc();
myPrint = myPrint.bind(p1);
myPrint();

//will pount to the global object where you declare the 2 properties
myPrint = p1.getFunc();
myPrint = myPrint.bind(globalThis);
myPrint();

//Will throw error as the this is undefined
myPrint = p1.getFunc();
myPrint();
```