# Precisely what is the return value of JavaScript's built-in `bind`?

Tags: javascript

Let's start with an example:

```js
let obj = { a: 'Amazebulous!' };

let otherObj = { a: "That's not a real word!" };

const foo = function() { console.log(this.a); };

let bar = foo.bind(obj);

bar.call(otherObj);
```

I have looked at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and other online resources. There seem to be two different models of `bind`'s return value.

In the above example, keep in mind that `bar` is the returned function, and `foo` is the function we'd like to bind to some context. Now, here are the two models I am seeing:

On the first model, `bind` returns `bar`, which is a higher-order function of `foo`. Function `bar` is not eternally bound to some context, but it always executes its internal `foo` function with the intended context. This is suggested by polyfills (including the first one on MDN) and "implementations" that give you an idea of how things work like:

```js
Function.prototype.bind = function (...args) {
  let fn = this;
  let context = args.shift();

  return function () {
    return fn.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

If this is the correct model, `bar` would be a higher-order function that executes `foo.apply(obj` whenever (or every time) it (`bar`) is executed. That is *not* the same as saying `bar` is permanently bound (indeed, we set `bar`'s context to `otherObj` in the above example), and that is *not* the same thing as saying `foo` is permanently bound (indeed, we can run `bind` on `foo` again with another context). Although we might say `foo` is permanently bound "inside" `bar`. If we wanted to bind `bar` to `obj` permanently, we'd have to additionally run `const baz = bar.bind(obj)`. In other words, `bar` and `foo` are not of the same type. If `foo` is a first-order function, then `bar` is a second-order function.

On the second model, `bind` returns `bar`, which is a strange, special function on the same order as `foo` and which does what `foo` does while being eternally bound to some context.

Which one is correct?

Another way of getting at the heart of the matter would be to answer what is happening on the last line of the original example. On the first model, `bar` is invoked while being bound to `otherObj`. However, `foo` is not bound to `otherObj` inside of `bar`. Inside of `bar`, `foo` is bound to `obj`. On the second model, JS does something (what?) to (a) not throw an error and (b) ignore `call` on `bar` so that `bar`'s context does not change. Put differently:

Why is it that when you invoke `bar` (even with `call` or `apply`), you get a result that behaves as if you're always invoking `foo` with the `obj` context?

On the first model, that's easy to explain. When you invoke `bar` with a `call`, you are not affecting the context of the "internal" `foo` call in which the context is explicitly set.

On the second model, I don't know how to explain why it is that when you invoke `bar` (even with `call`), you get a result that behaves as if you're always invoking `foo` with the `obj` context. It appears that *that* explanation would have to discuss something special about `bar`, but I don't know what it is because I don't really understand the second model. If this model is correct, why doesn't it throw an error when you're seemingly trying to change `bar`'s context? How does JS silence the `call` on `bar`?

I am now looking at the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.bind), and I'm not sure if it helps (I am a beginner; only coding for months). In any case, I'd appreciate clarification on this. It certainly matters for the interpretation of the original code example.

Finally, my question is *not* answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method). I know what the use of `bind` is. But I want to know more details about its return value and how it works (not why it is useful; it's obviously useful).

Comment: You should generally believe MDN.

Comment: What do you mean by "`bind` returns `bar`"? `bar` is a variable, it's not something that can be returned. `bind` returns a bound function object, and it's assigned to `bar`.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.

Comment: Your definition of `bind()` ignores the actual arguments that are supplied when you call the bound function. Notice how the polyfill in MDN concatenates `args` with `arguments`.

Comment: I would like to answer the question, but I've read it over and over and I can't figure out what distinction you're trying to make between the two models. It all seems to revolve around your notion of "permanently bound", which you haven't defined. Does that come from a spec?

Comment: When you say "You should generally believe MDN" do you mean that I should assume it essentially works as the polyfills specify? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The official spec is very hard to read because it's very abstract. MDN explanations and polyfills are more understandable. It might gloss over some details occasionally, but they're rarely critical.

Comment: But what I really meant is that if you found other online resources like tutorials, they usually won't be as good as MDN.