# how to access array elements outside a callback listener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

in the below posted code i am trying to access the e.coordinate from outside the callback listener `this.map.on('pointermove'...)` as shown below.
the method `routeToField()` is invoked on a button click. inside this method i am trying to access the values of `this.mousePointerLonLat`. the log statement inside the callback listener `this.map.on(...)` are displayed and contain
values in type of array with two elements.
the problem is, despite `this.mousePointerLonLat` is initialized, when it is accessed inside the method `routeToField()` i receive

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at SiteMapComponent.push.zIrq.SiteMapComponent.routeToFiel
```

please let me know how to access the values in the array `this.mousePointerLonLat` from inside the methos `routeToField`

**code**:

```
this.map.on('pointermove', (e)=>{
            this.mousePointerLonLat = toLonLat(e.coordinate);
        });

this.mousePointerLonLat = this.map.on.bind(this.mousePointerLonLat)
    console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat: ", this.mousePointerLonLat);
    console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat[0]: ", this.mousePointerLonLat[0]);
    console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat[1]: ", this.mousePointerLonLat[1]);
    var startLongitude = SynopsWebAppComponent.USER_COORDINATES.longitude;
    var startLatitude = SynopsWebAppComponent.USER_COORDINATES.latitude;
    var endLongitude = this.mousePointerLonLat[0];
    var endLatitude = this.mousePointerLonLat[1];
    this.openRouteServiceAPIService.getRouteAsVectorLayerBetweenStartEndLocations(startLongitude,startLatitude,endLongitude,endLatitude);
```

Comment: Use arrow function: `this.map.on('pointermove', (e) => { ... });`. See post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD i think you must re-read the question again

Comment: Your question isn't clear TBH. **1.** Are you sure the callback to `this.map.on('pointermove', ...)` would be triggered _before_ the button is clicked (or `routeToField()` is triggered)? **2.** Did you go through the attached post? Which variable do you think is accessed by `this.mousePointerLonLat` in a plain JS callback function? It accesses only within the scope of the callback. The class member variable is not initialized in a plain JS callback function. For that you need to use either `bind(this)` or arrow function.

Comment: @MichaelD would you please tell me how to use bind(this)?

Comment: @Letsamrit Read the post linked by Michael D. You are trying to access "this", but the two "this"-es are not the same.

Comment: @LetsamrIt: You could refer this post for `bind` usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD can you please provide some help to answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67175905/how-to-bind-on-array-to-have-access-to-it-outside-the-callback-listener

Comment: `bind` is for external callback handler. Why do you not use arrow function?

Comment: @MichaelD please check the updated question above. i use lambda function and external binding but still getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from my comments

The callback inside the `this.map.on('pointermove', {...})` is asynchronous. So if the button is pressed before the callback has been executed, the variable `this.mousePointerLonLat` would still be `undefined`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921) for more info on asynchronous operations.

One quick solution is to disable the button until the variable has been initialized. You could use the double-bang operator.

Controller (*.ts)

```js
this.map.on('pointermove', (e) => {
  this.mousePointerLonLat = toLonLat(e.coordinate);
});

routeToField() {
  console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat: ", this.mousePointerLonLat);
  console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat[0]: ", this.mousePointerLonLat[0]);
  console.log("this.mousePointerLonLat[1]: ", this.mousePointerLonLat[1]);
  var startLongitude = SynopsWebAppComponent.USER_COORDINATES.longitude;
  var startLatitude = SynopsWebAppComponent.USER_COORDINATES.latitude;
  var endLongitude = this.mousePointerLonLat[0];
  var endLatitude = this.mousePointerLonLat[1];

  this.openRouteServiceAPIService.getRouteAsVectorLayerBetweenStartEndLocations(
    startLongitude,
    startLatitude,
    endLongitude,
    endLatitude
  );
}
```

Template (*.html)

```html
<button [disabled]="!mousePointerLonLat" (click)="routeToField()">
  Route
</button>
```