# js method stored element property cannot access its properties

Tags: javascript

I made an Ajax request module using javascript and I store its object to form element attribute `formElement.ajax.ajaxmoduleA` .. like this.

After that I want to use this function more easily something like .. `formElement.ajaxA()` or assign the function directly on submit event but only I can get is `Cannot read properties of undefined`. I presume this happens from `this` command inside of object.

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 'a';
    }

    getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}

el = document.querySelector('#updateNameForm');
el.A = new A;
el.B = el.A.getA;
```

When I `el.A.getA.call()` console, same error pops.. How can I assign object function into element property? How about on event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use [`bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method) to ensure that `this` [is being handled correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method).
2. You forget to add open/close parentheses to your constructor call: `new A()`.

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 'a';
    }

    getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}

const el = document.querySelector('#updateNameForm');
el.A = new A();
el.B = el.A.getA.bind(el.A);
console.log(el.B())
```

```html
<div id="updateNameForm">Form</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be, because you're syntax is off. You need paranthesis to instantiate a new class or invoke a method:

```
el = document.querySelector('#updateNameForm');
el.A = new A();
el.B = el.A.getA();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fix the line:

```
el.A = new A();
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor method is a special method of a class for creating and initializing an object instance of that class that will be initialized by using the 'new' key word forward by the class name and the `()` parentheses after it

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 'a';
    }

    getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}

el = document.querySelector('#updateNameForm');
el.A = new A()
el.B = el.A.getA;
```