# Undefined object properties inside callback function in Worker Thread's parentPort listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, listener, worker-thread

I have a worker object something like this:

```
const WorkerObject = {
  mapProp: new Map(),

  funA() {
    // some task
  },

  funB() {
    // some task
  },

  workerListener() {
    parentPort.on('message', async (message) => {
      console.log(this.mapProp) // returning Map(0) {}
    })
  }
}
```

When I call `mapProp` property in `parentPort()` listener callback inside the `workListener()` function, it is referencing the Map that I have assigned at the top of the object. This is just what I expected.

But I need to reduce the Cognitive Complexity so I move the call back function to another defined function inside the `WorkerObject`.

```
const WorkerObject = {
  mapProp: new Map(),

  funA() {
    // some task
  },

  funB() {
    // some task
  },

  async doBulkIndex(message) {
    console.log(this.mapProp) // returning undefined
  },
  
  workerListener() {
    parentPort.on('message', this.doBulkIndex)
  }
}
```

But somehow, now the Map always returning undefined. Basically, all properties that I tried to access inside `doBulkIndex()` are undefined. Why is it like that? And how to make my second approach has the same behavior as the previous one?

Comment: the context of the callback that you call is not the same, I think you should bind "this" to it,  workerListener() {
    parentPort.on('message', this.doBulkIndex.bind(this))
  }

Comment: but what do you mean by `context` in `the context of the callback that you call is not the same`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

Comment: @alramdein you may want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the context of the callback that you call is not the same, I think you should bind "this" to it,

```
 workerListener() { parentPort.on('message', this.doBulkIndex.bind(this))}
```

at the first one, this keyword refers to WorkerObject But in the second one, this refers to "doBulkIndex" context. you can search about context and bind.

see: [bind keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)

so we manually change the context to main object using bind.

Comment: Citing from unattributed sources just above your answer is not a very constructive behavior.

Comment: thank you lajos, you are right. I add the link .