# I need help understanding 'Once' function by David Walsh

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments, this

I'm trying to understand exactly how this [Once function by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once) works:

`

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}

// Usage
var canOnlyFireOnce = once(function() {
    console.log('Fired!');
});

canOnlyFireOnce(); // "Fired!"
canOnlyFireOnce(); // nada
```

`

I understand it takes a function as a argument, and returns a function that calls the passed function only once.

But I'm trying to understand what each part is doing. Can anyone help explain? especially this part:

`result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);`

Why the OR sign? what is "this" and how is it getting the arguments from fn? What purpose does 'context' serve?

---

I wrote a similar once() function for school that returns the result of the passed function, and stores the result to return it again if the function attempts to get called again. It took a lot of trial and error, and I'm just trying to get a firm grasp on all the component parts of how this works.

`

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;  
}


function once(fn) {

  let timesRan = 0;
  let result;
  
  function doOnce() {
    if (timesRan === 0) {
      timesRan = 1;
      result = fn.apply(this, arguments); //I don't understand how this gets the arguments from AddOnce
      console.log(`did it once: ${result}`)
      return result;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }  
  return doOnce;

}


var addOnce = once(add);

console.log(addOnce(1, 2)); // test first call, expected value: 3
console.log(addOnce(2, 5)); // test second call, expected value: 3
console.log(addOnce(8, 22)); // test third call, expected value: 3
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept behind `this` in JavaScript is confusing, because when I write a function such as:

```
function getPersonName() {
    return this.name
}
```

I expect that `this` be defined as a some object with a `name` attribute. Depending on the scope, I may have this be defined and no problems! But in order for a function such as the above to properly reference `this`, we need to tell it what it should reference when we use that keyword.

For example, it allows us to do the following:

```
var canOnlyFireOnce = once(function() {
  console.log(this.name)
}, {name: "John"});

canOnlyFireOnce() // prints John
canOnlyFireOnce() // nada
```

It may be helpful to understand the [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115970/3813411) function's use cases in JavaScript to understand why having this (no pun intended) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `this` context in [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is already explained in [`rb612`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411205/13134095).

For the question about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), you need to know that

> the `arguments` object is a local variable available within all non-arrow functions. You can refer to a function's arguments inside that function by using its `arguments` object.