# Promises are not getting resolved before loop is over

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I'm trying to upload all files from  a folder with a drag&drop field. So once i drop the folder on my dropField, my `handleDrop()` is called. When all files are loaded (or rather stored in my `files` variable) I hand them over to my `this.loadFiles()` method which uploads them after some file testing to a server. However, the Promises inside `traverseDirectory` aren't resolved before the code goes on and the log *The FileArray:* gets logged and shows that `files` is still empty. But after that it prints me out, that the Promises get resolved one after the other. The first `item` that i get is a `FileSystemDirectoryEntry`, then i get from that (in my case, three files in a folder) three `FileSystemFileEntry` objects.

Question: How do I make sure my code doesn't execute further before all my files are retrieved = before all Promises are resolved?

my Javascript code:

```
retrieveFilefromFileEntry: async function (fileEntry, files) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fileEntry.file((file) => {
          resolve(file);
        });
      });
    },

handleDrop: function (ev) {
  const files = [];

  const items = ev.dataTransfer.items;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) {
      this.traverseDirectory(item, files);
    }
  }
  this.fileCount = files.length;
  console.log(`The FileArray: ${files}`);
  
  if (files.length > 0) {
    this.isUploadButtonVisible = true;  //variable to toggle the x-show of a button
    this.loadFiles(files);
  }
},

traverseDirectory: async function (item, files) {
  if (item.isFile) {
    await this.retrieveFilefromFileEntry(item, files).then((file) => {
      files.push(file);
    });
    console.log(`The Files are ${files}`);
  } else {
    const directoryReader = item.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries((entries) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        this.traverseDirectory(entry, files);
      }
    });
  }
},
```

[image: console error]

I try to load all Files before going on with my code.

Comment: Well your loop doesn't `await` anything before it finishes…

Comment: Well I think this is the basis of my question, I don't exactly know how to wait for the resolve of each promise...

Comment: When you call an async function, if you want to wait for it to finish, you need to call `await myAsyncFunction`

Comment: @Imdulz: `handleDrop` needs to be `async` as well and then it needs to use `await this.traverseDirectory(item, files)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi points out in the comment, you need to `await` for the files to be populated in the `files` array.

Here is a slightly different approach

```
function retrieveFilefromFileEntry(entry) {
  return new Promise(entry.file.bind(entry))
}
function readDirectory(item) {
  const directoryReader = item.createReader();
  return new Promise(directoryReader.readEntries.bind(directoryReader));
}
function fetchFiles(item, files) {
  if(item.isFile === true) {
    const file = await retrieveFilefromFileEntry(item, files);
    files.push(file);
  }
  else {
    const items = await readDirectory(item);
    for(let item of items) {
      await fetchFiles(item, files)
    }
  }
}
async function handleDrop (ev) {
  const files = [];
  const items = ev.dataTransfer.items;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
    if (item) {
      await fetchFiles(item, files);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I have written them as separate functions. I am sure you can put them together.

Comment: I think you forgot the `.createReader()` call, and your promisification does not work because the methods are not bound

Comment: @Bergi, sorry about that! Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't fix the second problem

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you took in consideration, that fileEntry.file is a method ? Or do I get wrong how you're using that in line2?

Comment: @lmdulz Yes, it needs to be either `new Promise((resolve, reject) => entry.file(resolve, reject))` or `new Promise(entry.file.bind(entry))`; and the same for `directoryReader.readEntries`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I still have no clue about Promises, and honestly dont get why await works with them (in basic understanding yes, but everywhere I read it said I have to use .then() functions instead...

Comment: @lmdulz `const r = await p` is the same as `p.then(r => …)` but with nicer syntax (and support for normal control structures)

Comment: @Imdulz In JavaScript, when you create a promise, you have to pass a function to it. Internally, JavaScript will call that function with two parameters. resolve & reject. 
In that function body, you need to do what you want to do & call either resolve or reject. When you want to return a value in promise, you would call resolve like this `resolve(data);`. Same way, when you want to throw an error, you would say `reject(new Error('This is not possile'))`. Now, when you look at the documentation of both entry.file & reader.readEntries, they both accept two parameters.

Comment: First one for success & second one for error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry/file#syntax & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryReader/readEntries#syntax

As they are same as what `Promise` expects, we can simply say `new Promise(entry.file)` and `new Promise(reader.readEntries)`. Now, JavaScript will call those functions automatically & the promise would work as expected. 

I see that @Bergi suggested to use `.bind(...)`. In this case, it is not needed. But, there are cases where you must do that.

Comment: @Bergi, I just realized my mistake. You are correct, probably they wont work without `.bind(...)`. 
@Imdulz updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your edit and your comments - could you elaborate, why I have to pass  `entry` back into `.bind()` inside `retrieveFilefromFileEntry`?

Comment: Same reason as `directoryReader.readEntries.bind(directoryReader)`. I can explain more, but I may not be able to beat the answers in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236747/6999951. Please check them out.